# Save data associated with webapplication without database

Tags: file, web-applications, tomcat, servlet-container

My task is to save and later read some arbitrary data in file inside webaplication. I cannot use hardcoded system paths, since there may be multiple instances of my webapp fired up on the same server. I have some limitations and cannot use database to manage this.
So, here is the question: is there any way to save arbitrary data associated with my webapplication instance using servlet container api. I use Tomcat 7 and can rely on this if needed.

Comment: why no database? have you considered to use in-memory database?

Comment: Of course, you have access to the file system using `java.io`, not nice, but it works. Problems arise when it comes to clustered solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some thing like this

1. Create a Folder under your web app let's call it webapp-data, keep it above WEB-INF folder
2. To access this path you can do some thing like this
3. String outputFolder = getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("webapp-data")
4. Although you are running multiple instances of same web app on the **server/jvm**, you cannot have same **context name** for all those web apps
5. Create a new file like with name String fileName = getServlet().getServletContext().getServletContextName()
6. String fullPath = outputFolder + File.pathSeparator + fileName + ".any extension";
7. Create file with full path and write to it, It will be unique and also will be tied to the instance of web app you deployed.